# How do I compact money into the fewest denominations?

Tags: arrays, math, language-agnostic, grouping

There's probably a term for this, but I don't know it, so searching is not easy.

I have a certain number of slots in an array. The number is not important, but it is fixed. In the end, I want the result to take the fewest number of slots with the highest denomination possible. Fewer slots is preferred over higher denomination.

I'll use money as my example. I have 10 slots in the array. Each slot can hold any denomination. I can use 100x $5, 100x $1, 40x 25¢, 50x 10¢, 40x 5¢, and 50x 1¢.

If I had $2, then I could do it as 2x $1 in 1 slot, optimally. That's a nice, clean number, though. If I have $21.13, then it is not as easy to calculate.
I could stack to the highest denomination:

```
slot[0] = 4x $5;
slot[1] = 1x $1;
slot[2] = 1x 10¢;
slot[4] = 3x 1¢;
```

but what I want is this, as it takes up fewer slots in the array:

```
slot[0] = 21x $1;
slot[1] = 13x 1¢;
```

Comment: Or 2113 x 1¢… I'm unclear what the boundaries or rules are here and what the question is exactly…

Comment: "I can use 100x $5, 100x $1, 40x 25¢, 50x 10¢, 40x 5¢, and 50x 1¢." Those are the maximum that can fit into a slot. It could be possible, but not optimal, to fill the slots with rolls of coins, but that's why the question exists.

Comment: OK, I overlooked that. Though if you have that as a condition, then having 10 slots seems to be pretty irrelevant (since you only have 6 denominations to work with anyway).

Comment: Indeed, the number of slots is irrelevant. The point is that there is a fixed number of slots, so I want to use as few of them as possible. 10 was just a number for the example.

Comment: I imagine this is some specific case of a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)…?

Comment: Maybe... You have definitely pointed me in the right direction, though. Thank you.